# How to figure out this definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate this definite integral?
$$\int_0^1\frac{x\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm{d}x$$
I've been thinking about this for a few days but still have no ideas.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! May I ask if there is a particular reason that you are studying exactly this integral? It looks like some random thing that is made up just to look hard. Also, it is good if you share your own thoughts and tries about it.

Comment: i got only a numerical value,$$0.321731$$

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk The answer cannot be negative : look at the integrand.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk I hadn't noticed you were working on a different issue : frankly, I don't see the point to consider this integral.

Comment: A non-elementary integral related to Bessel functions. Where does it arise? Would you be fine with a representation given by a fast-convergent series?

Comment: Actually I got this integrals from one of my friend in THU.At first,I tried to use the integral depending on a parameter,like $I(a)=\int_0^1\frac{\sin (ax)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm dx$.And I got $$I'(a)=\sqrt{2}\cos a-1+a\big [I(a)-I''(a)\big ]$$ But I found that  the solve of this differential equation is not elementary.Maybe there is something wrong with this problem.I'll ask him to check this integral for errors.Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer with **Kampé de Fériet Function**.
\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^1{\frac{x\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}\text{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\ln \left( 1+\sqrt{2} \right)}{\text{sinh}x\cos \left( \text{sinh}x \right)}\text{d}x  \ \ \ \ \ (x\rightarrow \mathrm{sinh}x)
\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n \right) !}}\int_0^{\ln \left( 1+\sqrt{2} \right)}{\text{sinh}^{2n+1}x\text{d}x}
\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\Gamma \left( n+1 \right)}{\Gamma \left( 2n+1 \right) \Gamma \left( n+\frac{3}{2} \right)}}\\
&\ \ \ -\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n2^k}{\Gamma \left( 2n+1 \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}+k \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}+n \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}+k+n \right)}}}\ \ \ \ \ (\text{with the help of MMA})
\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{L}_{-1}\left( 1 \right) -\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n2^k}{\Gamma \left( 2n+1 \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}+k \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}+n \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{2}+k+n \right)}}}
\\
&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{L}_{-1}\left( 1 \right) -\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( 1 \right) \!_n\left( 1 \right) \!_k}{\left( 1 \right) \!_n\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \!_n\left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \!_n\left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \!_k\left( \frac{3}{2} \right) \!_{n+k}}}}\frac{\left( -\frac{1}{4} \right) \!^n}{n!}\frac{2^k}{k!}
\end{aligned}
where $\mathbf{L}_{\nu}\left( z \right)$ is modified Struve function and by the definition of Kampé de Fériet Function
$$\displaystyle \mathbf{F}_{o,m,n}^{r,p,q}\left( \left. \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{A}_r;\mathbf{a }_p;\mathbf{a }_{q}^{'}\\[5pt]
 \mathbf{B}_o;\mathbf{b }_m;\mathbf{b }_{n}^{'}\\
\end{array} \right|x,y \right) =\sum_{i,j=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\prod_{s=1}^r{\left( A_s \right) \!_{i+j}}\prod_{k=1}^p{\left( a _k \right) \!_i}\prod_{\ell =1}^q{\left( a _{\ell}^{'} \right) \!_j}}{\prod_{v=1}^o{\left( B_v \right) \!_{i+j}}\prod_{t=1}^m{\left( b _t \right) \!_i}\prod_{u=1}^n{\left( b _{u}^{'} \right) \!_j}}}\frac{x^i}{i!}\frac{y^j}{j!}$$
where $\mathbf{a }_p=\alpha _1,\alpha _2,...,\alpha _p.$ Hence we have
$$\int_0^1{\frac{x\cos x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}\text{d}x=-\frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{L}_{-1}\left( 1 \right) -\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\mathbf{F}_{1,3,1}^{0,1,1}\left( \left. \begin{array}{c}
 1;1\\
 \dfrac{3}{2};1,\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2};\dfrac{3}{2}\\
\end{array} \right|-\frac{1}{4},2 \right) $$